# font awesome behavior with ng class

Tags: html, angular, font-awesome, ng-class

So my code is in angular version 5.

I have a button with an icon. I am trying to make the icon dynamic. 
So i want to shift between send icon `fa fa-paper-plane` and loading icon`fa fa-spinner fa-spin`. As and when I send a message I should show the spinner and when I get a message back, I should show the paper-plane icon.

Case 1) I gave `fa` along with `fa-spinner` and `fa-paper-plane` which didn't work.

```
<div class="send">
  <button type="submit" class="message-submit" id="btn-submit" (click)="onSubmit()">
    <i [ngClass]="{ 'fa fa-spinner fa-spin': true, 'fa fa-paper-plane': false }" aria-hidden="true" title="send"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

So this is the output below, where I get a square icon instead of the spinner.

[image: a square box appears]

Case 2) In this as well, I have given `fa` along with `fa-spinner fa-spin` and `fa-paper-plane`

```
<div class="send">
  <button type="submit" class="message-submit" id="btn-submit" (click)="onSubmit()">
    <i [ngClass]="{ 'fa fa-spinner fa-spin': false, 'fa fa-paper-plane': true }" aria-hidden="true" title="send"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

So now this happens.

[image: fa paper plane works]

So now you can see, between the two cases, I have just interchanged true false value. So I came to a conclusion that, my spinner is not working. 
But this happened,

Case 3) I have again given `fa` with `fa-spinner` and `fa-paper-plane`. But i have interchanged the position of `fa-spinner` and `fa-paper-plane` as you can see below.

```
<div class="send">
  <button type="submit" class="message-submit" id="btn-submit" (click)="onSubmit()">
    <i [ngClass]="{ 'fa fa-paper-plane': true, 'fa fa-spinner fa-spin': false }" aria-hidden="true" title="send"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

But this was the output, where I am again getting a box instead of paper-plane this time ( which I thought was working fine).

[image: fa-paper-plane not working]

Case 4) so now, below, you can see I have interchanged the true false values.

```
<div class="send">
  <button type="submit" class="message-submit" id="btn-submit" (click)="onSubmit()">
    <i [ngClass]="{ 'fa fa-paper-plane': false, 'fa fa-spinner fa-spin': true }" aria-hidden="true" title="send"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

And well, this gave me this output.

[image: got spinner finally]

Tada. Spinner is working too.

You can see from the four conditions, it is pretty clear that spinner as well as paper-plane is working properly, if it is placed in the **Second Position** in the [ngClass] directive.

Can someone please help me with a fix?

PS: Yes I am not using true and false ( I have a flag variable for it)

Comment: Better off is to have a component each icon so you can easy playing around

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to work best when the object's key is a single class.

You can instead do something like this:

```
class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-paper-plane': true, 'fa-spinner': false, 'fa-spin': false }"
```

Because the `fa` class should always apply, it's being done in a normal `class` attribute

Comment: This is what i have done. The temporary fix which i have done. But why is this behavior ?

Comment: Well you have 2 different rules for the same class, so one rule set to true, which is going to add `fa`, and the next rule set to false which is going to remove it

Comment: okay, like you told, i added one more fa-spinner at the end , just to see if it removes. But now, i'm getting a rotating `paper-plane` .

`<i [ngClass]="{ 'fa fa-spinner fa-spin': false, 'fa fa-paper-plane': true , 'fa fa-spinner fa-spin':'false' }">`

Comment: If the ngclass removes of the added fa class, then why is that not happeneing in the above case where I give a false condition again? Please elaborate or share some resource which I can refer. This is seriously making no sense to me

Comment: Because you're using `false` as a string there, not as a boolean

Comment: May be this is right. But i had no clue that it removes the existing classes as well. Thanks a lot

Comment: If it's set to false, it has to remove that class in order to work. Thats why if the boolean switches to false, the class is no longer applied (because it's removed). Feel free to check out the source code for more details https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/15cc85c54a9146c6d502cffad52a3c1a41fe4dcb/packages/common/src/directives/ng_class.ts

Comment: I see. I applied `fa` to normal class, and used the following sub-classes on NgClass, and it solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When a expression is evaluated to true the classes passed in ngClass are added to the classList for the element and when expression is evaluated to false the classes passed in ngClass are removed from the classList for the element. Example :

```
<div>
  <p>
    <i [ngClass]="{'fa fa-spinner fa-spin': false, 'fa fa-telegram-plane': false}"> </i>
    Random Text
  </p>

  <!-- DOM will have   <i> </i> -->

  <p>
    <i [ngClass]="{'fa fa-spinner fa-spin test test1234': true, 'fa fa-telegram test test1234' : false}"> </i>
    Random Text
  </p>

  <!-- DOM will have   <i class="fa-spinner fa-spin"> </i> -->


  <p>
    <i [ngClass]="{'fa fa-spinner fa-spin': false, 'fa fa-telegram': true}"> </i>
    Random Text
  </p>

  <!-- DOM will have   <i class="fa fa-telegram"> </i> -->

  <p>
    <i [ngClass]="{'fa fa-telegram test test1234': false, 'fa fa-spinner fa-spin test test1234': true}"> </i>
    Random Text
  </p>

  <!-- DOM will have   <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin test test1234"> </i> -->

</div>
```

Example Code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngclass-kmherp?file=app%2Fapp.component.html